# swagger-js client POST body missing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, swagger

I've created a generated a swagger-documentation defining a small api. I wanted to consume this in Vue.js with [swagger-js](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/).

All is working fine with the GET-requests but when I try to supply a requestBody to my POST, it is just simply dropped:

```
new SwaggerClient({ spec })
          .then(
              (client) => {
                client
                    .apis
                    .Beverage
                    .orderBeverage({
                      requestBody: {
                        id_user: 1,
                        id_beverage: 1,
                        quantity: 1
                      }
                    })
                    .then(data => {
                      console.log(data.body)
                    });
              });
```

The corresponding swagger-definition can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/mjqSGwJt), the full definition is [here](https://pastebin.com/xhQHYyEN).